# Move command fails with git filter-branch

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm currently trying to use `git filter-branch` to rename a directory in my repository.

The command I try to use, without success so far, is:

`git filter-branch --tree-filter "mv engine src" --force HEAD`

but this yields the following result:

> Rewrite dddd2d70eee09d5600f7aeb87ca8321be5ed6aee (1/888)mv: rename engine to src: No such file or directory
>
> tree filter failed: mv engine src

I don't understand why, as that simple move command works perfectly on its own... What's the directory/file that is not found, and how can I fix that?

I'm on MacOSX 10.10.5 and use zsh if it helps.

**Disclaimer**: I don't really care here for a discussion about doing a `git mv` or `mv` instead of that, I've already read about it and this is not the point here. I just want to know why this fails the way it does.

Comment: Can it be related to that some commits don't contain that directory? you can bypass it using `mv -f ....`

Comment: @Ferrybig It errors exactly the same way.

Comment: You could stick `ls -ld engine src` in your filter script to see whether either or both exists or not for the given commit.  You could `test -d engine && mv engine src` to see if that helps.  `mv -f` will still produce an error if the source file/directory is missing.

Answer (score 1):

It works with the `test && command || echo`

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'test -f engine && mv engine src || echo skipped' --force -- HEAD
```

For `windows` with [cmder](http://cmder.net) (you need to replace ' with ")

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "test -f engine && mv engine src || echo skipped" --force -- --all
```

Comment: `|| echo skipped` - a lovely dirty trick to stop it abandoning the whole effort!